# On the intersection of the hyperbolic paraboloid with a bundle of planes.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections

Suppose we are in Euclidian space in 3 dimensions.

I intersect a bundle of planes $\alpha(x-y) + z = 0$ with a hyperbolic paraboloid $x^2 - y^2 = 2z$

\begin{cases} \alpha(x-y) + z = 0 \\ x^2 - y^2 = 2z \end{cases}

\begin{cases} \alpha(x-y) + z = 0 \\ (x-y)(x+y+2 \alpha) = 0 \end{cases}

I don't understand what we obtain from this. I wrote that I obtain a family of lines but can't see it and would not be sure how to solve a system of this kind.

How do I see it and what is the way to solve these kind of systems?

Comment: How did you get $(x-y)(x+y+2 \alpha) = 0$? Looks like you substituted $z$ from the first equation, but the result is wrong.

Comment: @Aretino you are absolutely right I had an error in the equation of the hyperbolic paraboloid, thanks. Could you even help me in understanding why the result is a family of lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $(x-y)(x+y+2 \alpha) = 0$ is equivalent to either $(x-y)= 0$ or $(x+y+2 \alpha) = 0$, which are the equations of two planes. 
Combining the first one with $\alpha(x-y)+z = 0$, one gets $x=y$ and $z=0$,
the equation of a fixed line in the $(x,y)$-plane.
The other solutions of your system are then given by
$$
\begin{cases} 
\alpha(x-y)+z = 0 \\ 
x+y+2 \alpha = 0 
\end{cases}
$$
These are the equations of two planes, whose intersection is a line varying with $\alpha$, that is a family of lines.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Not a proper answer. I suppose you can study projections of intersections of various planes to the hyperbolic paraboloid. If that is the aim, however it is better to begin with:

\begin{cases} y = x \,\alpha \\ x^2 - y^2 = 2z \end{cases}

to get intersections by varying the inclination of cutting plane rotated around z-axis through  slope $\alpha$  { asymptotic lines , parabolas drooping down , parabolas opening up },

and then proceed with inclined planes as given in the problem.

$ z=0 $ gives a pair of asymptote straight lines of intersection, $ x = y, x = -y. $